# How do I correctly make my paragraph and list inline?

Tags: html, css

So I have this html & css code that im trying to get on the same line.
I'm pretty sure they are blockline thats why they are not on the same line.
How do i correctly make them stay on the same line on the website?
Sorry for not using jsFiddle, I really tried.

My first attempt:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Product Showcase</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <p id="Logo">VARGA NET</p>
      <ul id="navigation">
        <li>SPECIFICATIONS</li>
        <li>LOOK AT IT</li>
        <li>FEATURES</li>
        <li>FREE</li>
        <li>TESTIMONIALS</li>
        <li>HOME</li>
      </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background-image: url(Images/background.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

#Logo{
  color: White;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

li{
  color: white;
  float: right;
  padding: 8px;
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}
```

As you can see they are not on the same line so what I did was I tried putting them in a div and this is what I came u with. They are on the same line but I feel like I did it in a bad way.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Product Showcase</title>
  </head>
  <body>
          <div inline-block class="headerLogoAndMenu">
            <p id="Logo">VARGA NET</p>
            <ul id="navigation">
              <li>SPECIFICATIONS</li>
              <li>BUY NOW</li>
              <li>FEATURES</li>
              <li>PRICE</li>
              <li>TESTIMONIALS</li>
              <li>HOME</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.headerLogoAndMenu li{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  transition:0.5s;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 8px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-top: 16px;
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}
.headerLogoAndMenu #Logo{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  transition:0.5s;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do this...

```css
.headerLogoAndMenu {
  display: table;
}

.headerLogoAndMenu p {
  display: table-cell;
}

.headerLogoAndMenu ul {
  display: table-cell;
}

.headerLogoAndMenu ul li {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Product Showcase</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="headerLogoAndMenu">
      <p id="Logo">VARGA NET</p>
      <ul id="navigation">
        <li>SPECIFICATIONS</li>
        <li>BUY NOW</li>
        <li>FEATURES</li>
        <li>PRICE</li>
        <li>TESTIMONIALS</li>
        <li>HOME</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where does the "u" come from in .headerLogoAndMenu u { ?

Comment: @ChristofferNilsson sorry it was supposed to be `ul`. It's not really needed for just that simple snippet, but it's good to specify table-cell

Comment: Is there a way to make the list items side by side instead of on top of each other?

Comment: @ChristofferNilsson Yeah there you go, I edited my post. Just didn't use your styles because you can do that, my goal here is show you the relevant code.

Comment: Oooh! Makes sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this

```css
.headerLogoAndMenu {
  display: flex;
}

.headerLogoAndMenu ul {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Product Showcase</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="headerLogoAndMenu">
      <p id="Logo">VARGA NET</p>
      <ul id="navigation">
        <li>SPECIFICATIONS</li>
        <li>BUY NOW</li>
        <li>FEATURES</li>
        <li>PRICE</li>
        <li>TESTIMONIALS</li>
        <li>HOME</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used flexboxes for the layout of the logo and menu. Vertical alignment has been arranged in the center.

```css
.headerLogoAndMenu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

#navigation {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.headerLogoAndMenu li {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  list-style: none;
}

#Logo {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerLogoAndMenu">
  <p id="Logo">VARGA NET</p>
  <ul id="navigation">
    <li>SPECIFICATIONS</li>
    <li>BUY NOW</li>
    <li>FEATURES</li>
    <li>PRICE</li>
    <li>TESTIMONIALS</li>
    <li>HOME</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```